# Is my Kinect facial recognition data saved on the Xbox live cloud?

Tags: xbox-network

One of the new Xbox dashboard features is [cloud storage for your Live profile](http://majornelson.com/2011/06/06/cloud-storage-and-more-coming-to-xbox-live/) - apparently you can
[download your profile to another Xbox](http://support.xbox.com/en-GB/xbox-360/settings-and-initial-setup/profile-move-delete) with your points balance and friends list etc. But exactly what account data from my profile is stored in the cloud?

In particular, does it include the Kinect facial recognition data - can I go to a friend's house, download my profile and then walk straight on to Dance Central 2, say? Or would I need to retrain the facial recognition on that console too? If I copied my profile on a memory stick rather than downloading it would that work?

Comment: A gaming console download (personal) data from a cloud when it see's your face? THIS SCARES ME!

Comment: This is an excellent question.

Answer (score 4):

Kinect only saves your facial recognition data in its numerical form and only locally. Since the data is not sent to the cloud you won't be able to just sign into your account on a friends console. Here's a snippet from the Kinect Privacy website:

> Data Used for Sign-In. As an optional feature, Kinect can collect and use identity data to enable you to sign in to your gamer profile. This is mostly facial recognition data that identifies individual players. You can decide whether to use this feature, called Kinect ID, and control whether this data is collected. **This data is stored permanently on your console to enable sign in to your gamer profile, and is not returned to Microsoft.** This information is stored as a long series of numbers, and it does not personally identify you.

Copying your profile however could work since it will take the local data associated with your account but I don't have a Kinect to confirm it :( Sorry. For more information you could check out the link

> **Source:** [**Kinect Privacy and Online Safety**](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/kinect/privacyandonlinesafety#DataCollection1)

Hope that helps :)

Comment: OK, thanks - I'd read [the identity question](http://www.xbox.com/en-US/kinect/privacyandonlinesafety#identity1) which doesn't have the 'returned to Microsoft' but missed that. That said, I'd expect that FAQ was written before the cloud feature.